# VB.net Key Combinations doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

The following code works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, and <kbd>F7</kbd>, but does not work for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.  Anyone know what the issue could be?

```
Private Sub AgentSetupForm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        '  Ctrl + A
        Case Keys.A And (e.Control And Not e.Shift And Not e.Alt)
            Dim f As New InvestorAccountsForm
            f.MdiParent = TraderoomMDI
            f.Show()

            '  Ctrl + D 
        Case Keys.D And (e.Control And Not e.Shift And Not e.Alt)
            Dim f As New InvestorAddressForm
            f.MdiParent = TraderoomMDI
            f.Show()
            '  F2, F7 
        Case Keys.F2 'And (e.Shift And Not e.Control And Not e.Alt)
            Me.Text = "F2 Test"
        Case Keys.F7
            stlFormMode.Text = "Edit"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Since Ctrl-A is the Windows shortcut for "select all text", the key combination might be captured before it reaches the general KeyDown handler of your form. What happens if your try the PreviewKeyDown event instead?

Comment: Make sure KeyPreview property of the form is True

Comment: The KeyPreview is set to TRUE and nothing happens with the PreviewKeyDown event.  As a matter of fact, it doesn't even hit in debug.  I thought about the CTRL + A being select all, but there should be a way to override that...well maybe.

Comment: Select on e.KeyData instead.  Now you can write `Case Keys.A Or Keys.Control`

Comment: Just made a little update to my answer, thanks to Bozhidar Stoinev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As it seems you have an issue with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> combination, you could try overriding `ProcessCmdKey` and see if that works. The method should be called before the keys are handled and/or translated by the .NET environment.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.A) Then
        ...your code here...
        Return True
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

If the other combinations work you can keep them in the `KeyDown` event.

---

**EDIT 2:**

@BozhidarStoinev is right about what he says; I was wrong saying that you're currently using the bitwise And.

Apparently it works using `And` or `AndAlso` in `Select Case`-statements due to how boolean values are converted in VB.NET. In this case as long as the first operator is just `And` you'll be fine. The following `AndAlso`s below are used because they perform shortcircuiting, which is faster due to that `AndAlso` only evaluates the right side if the left side is `True`.

The following:

```
Keys.A And (e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt)
```

converts to either:

```
(65 And True) = (65 And -1) = 65 'I added parentheses for improved readability
```

or:

```
(65 And False) = (65 And 0) = 0
```

It is not certain that multi-statement cases will work every time however. It might work for keys, but as `<anything> And False` equals to zero there is a chance for unexpected results if you are checking for 0 in another `Case`.

Comment: So changed it to an if statement with your recommendations.  Ctrl + A still didn't work.  Did I miss something?

Comment: If e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso (e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt) Then
            Dim f As New InvestorAccountsForm
            f.MdiParent = TraderoomMDI
            f.Show()
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.D AndAlso (e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt) Then
            Dim f As New InvestorAddressForm
            f.MdiParent = TraderoomMDI
            f.Show()
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
            Me.Text = "F2 Test"
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F7 Then
            stlFormMode.Text = "Edit"

        End If

Comment: @Levi : Hold on, will try it. I wrote the answer on my phone so debugging it was not possible. Did you try showing a MessageBox or something?

Comment: No, just looking for the new form to open.  Nice job on the cell phone however!  Kudos!

Comment: @Levi : I just copied the code from your comment and changed what the statements does. It works fine for me.

Comment: @Levi : What do you have in your form? Maybe it's a TextBox or something stealing the focus? Try adding `MessageBox.Show("Hello")` to execute after the `If e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso ... Then` part.

Comment: Strange!  I added the messagebox to Ctrl+A and it still does not work.  Ctrl+D works fine.

Comment: @Levi : What comes up if you add this **before** your first `If`-statement: `If e.KeyCode <> Keys.ControlKey Then MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString() & " - " & e.Control & " - " & (e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt) & " - " & e.KeyData.ToString())` _(it's a one-liner, you can just copy-paste it from the comments)_

Comment: Nothing!  Looks like e.KeyCode and Keys.ControlKey are =

Comment: On the D its D - True - True - D

Comment: @Levi : Seems like either your computer or your application has a problem with your keyboard. What happens if you change the first one from `e.KeyCode.ToString()` to `Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyCode)`?

Comment: Nothing on Ctrl+A, but if I place the Convert.ToInt... in a messagebox by itself, it shows 17.

Comment: @Levi : Well you were supposed to put it in the message box that _should be before_ the entire `If`-statement. 17 is `ControlKey`. Try pressing just A and tell me the number it shows.

Comment: I did, and the answer was nothing.  Sorry I didn't make that clearer.  With A is says 65 - False - False - A

Comment: Okay, so it works if you press `CTRL` or `A` but not both at the same time. I think your issue reside elsewhere than your application. You could always try overriding `ProcessCmdKey`. Let me update my answer for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Just as a test, I changed it to Ctrl+Q and it worked so maybe it has something to do with "Select All" being reserved?  Seems like I should be able to define it in my app like I want, but maybe not.  Your the best!

Comment: @Levi : No problem, glad I could help! Though I don't think it's related to `CTRL + A` being the standard action "Select All"... To me it seems like there's something else behind the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is totally incorrect.
VB.NET is not C#. So if `And` is used in a context with `Boolean`s (on the both sides) VB.NET automatically switches to logical `And` as opposed to bitwise `And`. So this is not a problem at all. I just run the OP code and it ran fine - Ctrl + A combination was captured successfully. Furthermore, if a key combination means something for the OS (or some other component) it doesn't mean it won't be captured in *our* application.

The difference between `And` and `AndAlso` is that the first evaluates the Boolean expressions from left to right all along to the end, even though some of the expressions evaluates to `False`. The later evaluates expressions UNTIL it reaches `False` or to the end - that is *short-circuiting*.

To improve the readability of your code you can test for a particular key at the `Case` statement. Then insert an `If` block within the particular case to check the condition of control keys:

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.A 
        If e.Control AndAlso Not (e.Shift OrElse e.Alt)
            Dim f As New InvestorAccountsForm
            f.MdiParent = TraderoomMDI
            f.Show()
        End If
    '
    '
End Select
```

Or you can factor out the `If` block to embrace the `Select Case` for all the cases concerning the condition `e.Control AndAlso ...`.

Unfortunately I cannot answer your question as it seems your issue cannot be (easily) reproduced. Based on the comments, it is more likely to be hardware or driver related problem than the `Case` statements in your code.

Comment: I see. The reason it works though is that `Keys.A And True` returns 65, probably because `True` is converted into -1 which results in `65 And -1 = 65`. `Keys.A And False` results in `65 And 0 = 0`. I'm not certain if this logic will work in all situations.

Comment: I also updated my answer and removed the incorrect statement(s). Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old
But it works easily

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case keyData
        Case (Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + Keys.Alt + Keys.B)
            MsgBox("Control + Shift + Alt + B")
            Return True
        Case Keys.Control + Keys.Alt + Keys.C
            MsgBox("Control + Alt + C")
            Return True
    End Select


    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```